# Using ribbon button inside wiki page

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm kind of new to SharePoint and still a student so I don't have much programming skills.
I'm trying to add the 'upload file' button from the ribbon into my Enterprise Wiki template ( EnterpriseWiki.aspx ) This way people can add attachments to the page in no time. Is this possible?
Thanks for the help !
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need programming skills to use SharePoint. A wealth of functionality can be achieved by just using the browser GUI.

The Enterprise Wiki page content type does not allow uploading files out of the box. You would have to add the attachment column to the content type and then edit the Enterprise Wiki page layout to include that column. This requires using SharePoint Designer and may be daunting for beginners.

It may be easier if you just created a document library, upload the document to the library and insert a link to the document in the Enterprise Wiki page.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've allready used a bit of SharePoint designer to change the EnterpriseWike.aspx page. I've added this : <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="PageContent" html="<span><p>this will be shown on every new wiki page</p></span>"> now i want to add the upload file button from the ribbon on this page template is this possible? i cant use a doc library cause if i have 10 pages with different attachment on those pages, all the attachments will be shown on all the pages.

Comment: Hold your horses. You cannot just add a control to the page and hope it will do what you want. The Enterprise wiki page content type does not ***have*** a column for attachments. You need to ***add*** the relevant site column to the content type first. Then you can add the column to (one of the) edit mode panel(s) and the display fields. Typically, Enterprise Wiki pages don't ***do*** file attachments. I also don't see why you can't use a doc lib and post links. Why not? Just edit the text in the page an insert a link. And another link. And another link. ...

Comment: ... Or, if you want the links to the documents to be a fixed part of certain pages, use page layouts with links to the docs. Or add a filtered list view wp to the page layout. Or a CQWP that shows related documents. or... or.. or.... There are many more possibilities than you can imagine right now. The point is that you are just starting with SharePoint and that you may be taking a completely wrong approach to solve the business need, based on limited understanding of SharePoint. You have an idea about how you want to solve it. That may be a wrong approach. What is the functional spec?

Comment: From a document management perspective, adding attachments to list items is the least preferable way of dealing with files in SharePoint. There is no version control, no document metadata, no search indexing, etc. A doc lib will provide all that functionality and more. A page can accommodate views of a doc lib either as a fixed part of the page layout (parametrized and filtered if need be), an inserted web part, or links can be added manually in the body text of the page. The linked documents can be managed, versioned, retired, etc. in their own proper space, i.e. a doc lib.

Comment: Teylen
Thanks for the reply! To give you al little bit more information :I'm using the SharePoint Enterprise wiki pages to set up a knowledge base for the company. Every wiki page is an article that describes a certain problem and it's solution. I've allready noticed that it's possible to attach a file on a wiki page by using the ribbon : insert => insert file. A link will apaer on the page to the file and the file is stored in my document library attachments i created. Now I thought this was the hard way and so many clicks to get the attachment on the page.I want the upload button on the wiki

Comment: I hope this is possible. I've allready made some adjustments in the template that i get a table every time i open a new wike page. I want the button to be inside the tabel if it's possible.

Comment: You can add a button that calls the same javascript than the ribbon button. That javascript is not easily accessible, though. The ribbon is always visible. Why not just teach your users to click the ribbon icon instead of a button in the page? Don't re-invent the wheel. Educate the users.

Comment: Teylen i think i will have to do it this way. My teacher asked me if this was possible to save the users some time. But as you say it would be a bit stupid to re-invent the wheel. I will educate the users to use the ribbon instead. Thanks !